# ArrayStoreException when trying to fill a float array

Tags: java, exception

Why does the following code raise an exception and what does it mean?

```
float[][] foo_array = new float[WIDTH][HEIGHT]; //Assume WDITH and Height are defined
java.util.Arrays.fill(foo_array, Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
```

As you can see, I'm just trying to initialize the float array at infinity but this is causing the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.Float
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:113)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.Float
at java.util.Arrays.fill(Arrays.java:2170)
```

Of course I can just iterate through the whole array and set each value to infinity, and I'm aware that's what the fill method does anyway (how else could it work). But I'm just curious about why this doesn't work and what is this exception.

EDIT: I omitted a big part of the exception message as I didn't want to make this so long and it wasn't providing any relevant information.

Comment: what has `foo_array` to do with filling `distmap`, and what is the declaration of `distmap`

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, foO_array is actually distMap, I just changed the name to make it more general and didn't pay attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [JLS 10.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.5)

> If the type of the value being assigned is not assignment-compatible (§5.2) with the component type, an ArrayStoreException is thrown.

It seems that your `distMap` reference is not a `float[]` , may be a `float[][]` which will not work , because `float[]` is not equivalent to `float[][]`.

Try with a correct parameter like `foo_array[0]` , it works:

```
float[][] foo_array = new float[10][10]; //Assume WDITH and Height are defined
java.util.Arrays.fill(foo_array[0], Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(foo_array));
```

Also look at the method signature of [fill(float[] a,
        float val)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(float[],float)).

You need to iterate through `foo_array` and set each `foo_array[i]` . Sample :

```
for(float[] floatArrays:foo_array) {
    java.util.Arrays.fill(floatArrays, Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
}
```

Here is a nice [tutorial on multi-dimensional arrays](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c7/s5.html).

[image]

Comment: Note that a float[][] is not a float[]. It is an array of references to float[].

Comment: Okay, so there is not way to fill the whole array at once. Thank you very much, I'll just iterate through the whole array, so I don't depend on any external method as I have to use loops anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`foo_array` is a `float[][]`, which makes it clear why your attempt fails: the element type of `foo_array` is `float[]`. That's how Java's multidimensional arrays work: they are arrays of arrays.

To correct your problem, iterate over all `float[]`-typed members of `foo_array` and use `Arrays.fill` against each of them.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just edited that. They were the same thing, I just changed the name to make my question less specific. My bad

Comment: So there is no way to fill the whole multidimensional array? Like C++'s

    vector<vector<int> > v (HEIGHT,vector<int>(WIDTH,FILL_VALUE));

Comment: Not with a built-in function. You can certainly write your own, or find one in a public library :) I think in C++ the semantics are the same (vector of vectors), just the library happens to have direct support for it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you should use this loop to do what you want:

```
for(int i = 0; i < foo_array.length; i++){
   Arrays.fill(foo_array[i], Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is going to invoke following method in java.util.Arrays

`public static void fill(Object[] a, Object val) {

    for (int i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++)

            a[i] = val;

    }`
Hence your exception is as expected.